# Can't print char** outside of getline() while loop

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, double-pointer

Trying to read a file from commandline argument with getline() and store into char**, but when I try to access the data inside like using printf(), it prints nothing. Although printf() works fine within the while loop after each getline().

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //open file
    FILE *stream = NULL;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t nread;
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    stream = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (stream == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //read file line by line
    char ** input = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, stream)) != -1)
    {
        j++;
        input = (char **)realloc(input, sizeof(char*) * j);
        input[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(line));
        input[i] = line;

        //print each line (PRINTS FINE)
        printf("%s",input[i]);
        i++;
    }

    //print each line outside of while loop (PRINTS NOTHING)
    for (int z = 0; z < j ; z++)
    {
        printf("%s",input[z]);
    }
}
```

Welcome to try with any .txt file like this

```
./a.out input.txt
```

Comment: edited to increment j, still doesn't print anything

Comment: OT: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: `input[i] = line;` don't make sense, you erase your previous allocation !

Comment: regarding: `input[i] = line;` after the next call to `getline()`, that char * will be pointing to memory that is no longer part of your program.  Suggest: `strcpy( input[i], line);`

Comment: thanks for the tip! Using strcpy(input[i], line) seems to fix the problem!

Comment: I was first thinking that your code was just keeping the pointer to the 'line'.  And no, `strdup()` does not do the same thing.  `strdup()` makes a copy (somewhere in the heap) of the original string, then returns a pointer to that copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not printing. It is in reading and storing.

1. `sizeof(char) * strlen(line)` must be `sizeof(char) * (strlen(line) + 1)` (you did not allocate space for the NULL terminator). In fact,  `(strlen(line) + 1)` will suffice (see the comment by @user3629249), and even `(len + 1)` (because `len` holds the length of the read string).
2. `input[i] = line;` does not create a copy of a string. You must use `strcpy(input[i], line);`.
3. Finally, you must `free(line)` at the end.

Comment: thanks, using strcpy(input[i],line) solved the problem! :D

Comment: the expression: `sizeof( char )` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect (and just clutters the code)

Comment: @user3629249 I know and agree, but it does not hurt, either.

Comment: actually, such useless code does hurt.  It makes the code more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: "Finally, you must free(line) and set it to NULL at the end of each iteration. Otherwise, getline may not allocate enough space and you will have a memory leak." what ? that the purpose of getline to not free line each time but only at the end of the parsing !

Comment: @Stargateur You are right. The buffer still must be freed later on.

Comment: @user3629249 I've never seen anyone who had problems understanding `sizeof(char)`. In theory, you may be right. Practically, it does not matter.